# Tomcat 9 - using non plaintext password for manager-gui not working correctly

Tags: tomcat

I try to set a up a new Tomcat 9.0.11 with manager-gui enabled and with hashed passwords in tomcat-user.xml for manager login. I follow 
http://www.peter-eichenauer.de/safari/blog/entry/tomcat_9_understanding_credentialhandler

and I can login into the manager-gui BUT not with the real password but only the hashed password string. So it is likely that Tomcat uses the hashed password as real password but I set the

```
<CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="sha-256">
```

in the server.xml. So I don't know what to do. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you place that element? Please add more `server.xml` to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I made a mistake in the server.xml:
Instead of:

```
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase" >
            <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="sha-256" />
  </Realm></Realm>
```

I wrote:

```
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="sha-256" />
  </Realm>
```

A stupid closing Realm mistake. Thanks to all!!!!

Comment: I had the same issue but I wonder why there is no error when that tag is not closed. Thank you for your question and solution

Comment: CredentialHandler tag under Realm is important, i was trying without the tag and it was not working, this answer helped great !

Answer (score 2):

For me it is working this way:

**server.xml:**

```
...
 <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase">
           <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="sha-256"/>
    </Realm>
  </Realm>
```

And generating the digest (on Windows) using:

```
#> cd path\to\apache-tomcat\bin
#> digest.bat -a sha-256 myPassword
myPassword:f75445d56beaa5767c5d79530f2251eab6f23704b56a513b68f1d075cb64e252$1$cc7f241d7b62f0653d3ca944988a610c05c635a89f33be93ec534f9e0bef0a72
```

Then the tomcat-users.xml looks like this for me:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0"> 
  <user
       username="myAdminUser"
       password="f75445d56beaa5767c5d79530f2251eab6f23704b56a513b68f1d075cb64e252$1$cc7f241d7b62f0653d3ca944988a610c05c635a89f33be93ec534f9e0bef0a72"
       roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-script,manager-status"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: The same configuration on my side. I can only login with the long hashed password not with the real password. I don't know what is wrong here. Maybe the OS? I use RHEL 7.

Comment: Tried also on my Windows client with Tomcat 9.0.13. Same result.

Comment: Tried also with Tomcat 8.0.53. This is working! But no real solution.

Comment: Sounds strange - I just downloaded http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-windows-x64.zip  and only altered server.xml and tomcat-users.xml. I can login using myAdminUser + myPassword : https://pastebin.com/vp3AXmvt

Comment: JRE 1.8.0_162-b12 / Oracle Corporation